# How to Integrating Phonegap plugin in Mobile web app for Barcode scanner?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

We are trying to integrate phonegap plugin for Barcode scanner in our Mobile web app. Can any one help me in integrating this?

I added, Phonegap.js and cardova.js, the plugin try to install but it takes so much time and not installing..

Here is my HTML content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Bar code Reader</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="barcodescanner.js"></script>
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
app.initialize();
});
function clickScan() {
console.log("I am now scanning");
window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function (result) {
alert("We got a barcode\n" +
"Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
"Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
"Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
}, function (error) {
alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
});
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="scan" style="padding: 10px;" onclick="clickScan">Scan!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: link github for barcode scanner phonegap plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps

1.Download and install `Node.js`

2.run this command on command prompt `$ sudo npm install -g phonegap`

3.create an application named hello`$ phonegap create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`

4.go to hello directory `$ cd hello`

5.chose your platform  i am showing you for ios you can build it for Android too

```
 $ phonegap build ios
[phonegap] detecting iOS SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling iOS...
[phonegap] successfully compiled iOS app
```

6.add plugin that you want to add `phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/BarcodeScanner.git`

7.To compile your app remotely, prefix the build command with the additional remote command: `$ phonegap remote install ios
    # ...or...
    $ phonegap remote run ios`

Comment: Can you share me more details on how/Where should I add this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the Barcode Scanner plugin usage:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Barcode Scanner DEMO</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/plugin-loader.js"></script>   
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

monaca.viewport({width : 320});

function scanBarcode() {
  window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan( function(result) {
          alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                    "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                    "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                    "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, function(error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
);

}
</script>
</head>

<hr> BarcodeReader DEMO <hr><br>
<input type="button" onClick ="scanBarcode()" value ="Scan" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hope you are not talking about Hybrid applications. I could see Monaca is for Hybrid Apps. I need plug in for my web site (webapp) in mobile.